Identities used in solving logarithmic integrals
This question intends to collect the various identities one can use to solve logarithmic integrals.

While solving this question, I came across a plethora of logarithmic integrals which involved a product of logarithmic terms in the numerator
I have noticed using some beautiful identities one can break down complicated logarithmic products into simpler trivial integrals but certain identities are not so obvious sometimes ( especially  for the heavy weighted integrals ).
Here are some identities I have used/noticed it being used so far to break up logarithms in product,

\begin{align}
ab & =\frac{1}{4}(a+b)^2-\frac{1}{4}(a-b)^2
\\[2mm]
ab & =\frac{1}{2}a^2+\frac{1}{2}b^2-\frac{1}{2}(a-b)^2
\\[2mm]
ab & =\frac{1}{2}(a+b)^2-\frac{1}{2}a^2-\frac{1}{2}b^2
\\[2mm]
ab^2 & =\frac{1}{6}(a+b)^3+\frac{1}{6}(a-b)^3-\frac{1}{3}a^3
\\[2mm]
a^2b & =\frac{1}{6}(a+b)^3+\frac{1}{6}(a-b)^3-\frac{1}{3}b^3
\\[2mm]
a^3b & =\frac{1}{4}a^4-\frac{1}{4}b^4+\frac{1}{16}(a+b)^4-\frac{5}{16}(a-b)^4-\frac{1}{2}(a-b)^3b
\\[2mm]
ab^3 & = \frac18 (a + b)^4 − \frac18 (a − b)^4 − a^3 b
\\[2mm]
ab^2-a^2b & =\frac13(a-b)^3-\frac13a^3+\frac13b^3
\\[2mm]
ab & = \frac14(a+b)^2 −\frac14(a−b)^2
\\[2mm]
a^3 b & = \frac14a^4 + \frac14b^4 − \frac14(a − b)^4 − ab^3 + \frac32a^2 b^2
\\[2mm]
a^2b^2 & =\frac{1}{12}(a+b)^4+\frac{1}{12}(a-b)^4-\frac16a^4-\frac16b^4
\end{align}
$$20a^3b^2=(a+b)^5+(a-b)^5-2a^5-10ab^4$$

Also, apart from usage of identities, what are the other ways to split a product of logarithmic terms to simplify the integral into known/trivial integrals/series ?.
One is using the Cauchy product like the following;

\begin{align}
\frac{\log(1-x)\log(1+x)}{1-x} & =
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\!\!\frac12 \bar{H}_n^2+\bar{H}_n^{(2)}-\frac12H_n^{(2)}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\bar{H}_k}{k}\!\!\right)x^n
\\[2mm]
\frac{\log(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1-x} & =\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(2{H}_n^{(3)}-H_nH_n^{(2)}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{{H}_k}{k^2}\right)x^n
\\[2mm]
\frac{\log(1+x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1-x} & =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\!\!{H}_n^{(3)}-\bar{H}_n^{(3)}-\bar{H}_n\bar{H}_n^{(2)}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\bar{H}_k}{k^2}\!\!\right)x^n
\end{align}

How do we extend this idea for a product of more than $2$ logarithmic terms ?.
One could apply these identities repeatedly, but do identities that exist in any text/references that evaluate $3$ or more
logarithmic product terms.

Edit :
Found these cool multipurpose identity,
\begin{align*}
&(a-b)^3b = a^3b - 3a^2b^2 + 3ab^3 - b^4 = -2a^3b +3(a^3b+ab^3) -3a^2b^2 -b^4\\
&\Longrightarrow \ \ \ 2a^3b = -{b^4 \over 2} -{b^4 + 6a^2b^2\over 2} + 3(a^3b+ab^3) - (a-b)^3b
\end{align*}
$$a^4b^3=\frac{1}{70}\left(a+b\right)^7-\frac{1}{70}\left(a-b\right)^7-\frac{1}{5}a^6b-\frac{3}{5}a^2b^5-\frac{1}{35}b^7$$
